# Complex filter in Excel using AND/OR Nesting

Tags: sql, excel

Is it possible to create a filter in Excel across multiple columns with AND/ORs, or what's the suggested way to do this? For example:

```
 WHERE
 (Name = "Tom" AND country in ['US', 'CA']) 
    OR 
 (Age > 14 and country not in ['FR', 'DE'])
```

If not, how does one normally do a SQL-like filter clause in Excel, or is this considered too much of an edge case for Excel to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=OR(AND(Name="Tom", OR(country="US", country="CA")),
    AND(Age > 14, AND(country<>"FR", country<>"DE")))
```

The trick is that using `AND`/`OR` with Excel requires nesting the logic, which is different than how SQL does it.

You may replace `Name` and `country` with the actual Excel cells which contain that particular data.

Comment: `AND()` can take more than 2 arguments, so nesting `AND()` is not necessary.

Comment: @Tim -- oh, I see. So you'd add an additional column with **that** formula and then filter on the single new column?

Comment: @David542 I don't know what your ultimate goal is here, I have only tried to represent the `WHERE` clause logic using Excel code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see. Yes, I'm trying to filter to only those rows (like a basic Excel filter on a column).

Comment: Then you may filter using the above formula as a computed column.  There should be an option to turn on/off rows based on whether they match or don't match this formula.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. Where would I enter in a formula then? https://imgur.com/a/hoJ0Rer. Would I have to first create a column...enter a formula for that columns, and then in that columns just choose value=TRUE ?

Comment: Just choose Sort -> Filter from the top ribbon.  Then filter the column containing this formula on either true, false, or both.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, `AND` and `OR` are functions. See [Excel / Formulas and functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formulas-and-functions-294d9486-b332-48ed-b489-abe7d0f9eda9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=Logical).

Example:

`=OR(AND(B2="Tom", OR(B3="US", B3="CA")), AND(B4>14, B3<>"FR", B3<>"DE")))`

Comment: This answer was already given by another user 3 minutes earlier.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see that (now). Wasn't there when I hit submit.

Answer (score 1):

With the new Dynamic Array formulas (available in most versions of Office 365), the list can be filtered with the Filter() function and the result is displayed outside of the list.

The screenshot shows Tim Biegeleisen's formula with conditional formatting to highlight the TRUE values before filtering the table on that column. Next to that is the result of **ONE** formula in cell H2, which has automatically spilled to the right and down. For ease of identification, I have included an index column.

Note that AND logic is built with the multiplication operator, whereas OR logic uses the addition operator.

```
=FILTER(Table1,
((Table1[Name]="Tom")*((Table1[Country]="US")+(Table1[Country]="CA")))+
((Table1[Age]>14)*(Table1[Country]<>"FR")*(Table1[Country]<>"DE")))
```

[image]